# How to host a C program online

Tags: c++, c, apache, web-hosting

I have created a program in c++ and now i wish to run it on my blog.Is this possible? If yes please give a detailed explanation of the process.Since i have no prior experience on stuff this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of a user interface does this program have? I.e. does it process files, does it expect interactive input, does it accept network connections, ...

Comment: Do you mean you want to run your C++ code in a server to interact with HTTP requests? Then you should read about CGI.

Comment: There are lots and lots of options all of which would take far too long to explain in a web forum. You do need to provide some details of what your program does, so someone can give you some ideas to pursue.

Comment: The program is a console application it fetches data from a file based on user input and displays the same @Joni

Comment: Can you suggest me any articles or give me any links @john

Comment: @user2828329 I would agree with MM, CGI is probably the simplest option, but you are going to have to change your code, and the environment in which your blog is hosted makes a difference. You might have to pay more for them to allow you to host a CGI program for instance.

Comment: @user2828329 Here's a basic CGI in C++ tutorial, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm, I only skimmed it so I can't really vouch for it's quality.

Comment: It largely depends on what sort of access you have to the webserver. If your webserver is programmed in, say, PHP, you could simply use `system("myprog arg1 arg2")` or `$handle = popen("myprog arg1 arg2");` - but beware that a hosting service most likely won't supply a compiler or even allow random executables to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [CGI C/C++ Tutorial](http://www.purplepixie.org/cgi/howto.php) might be of help.